# searching a string and finding content of adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel, match

I have an excel sheet named "indications" in the same directory where the excel sheet "tool" which contains my macros are there. The excel sheet indications have around 400 rows and 20 columns of data.

I have a macro that will take a string input from the user (for eg: DUMMY_TEXT ) and run another macro. The another macro is where I am struck.

I have to search that string input DUMMY_TEXT in the excel sheet "indications" in the Column D and find the contents of column Q,R,S and T in the corresponding row in which string input was found. This has to happen dynamically according to the user input.

I am struck at finding the contents of column Q,R,S and T. This is what I have now

```
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range

temppath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Workbooks.Open (temppath + "\indications.xlsx")

Set FoundCell = Range("D1:D20000").Find(what:=LSearchValue, lookat:=xlWhole)

Workbooks("indications.xlsx").Close
```

Comment: You didn't care to disclose the name of the worksheet...?

Comment: forgot to change it while copying the code. thanks for reminding me

Comment: Your code and narrative confuses the terms **workbook** and **worksheet**. A [Workbook Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) is not the same thing as a [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For a `lookat:=xlWhole` match in a single column, I prefer the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) use of the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) over the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

```
Sub trwqoeiryg()
    Dim findThis As Variant, rw As Variant, wb As Workbook
    Dim strQ as string, strR as string, strS as string, strT as string
    findThis = "find This"

    'VB/VBA uses an ampersand as the preferred string concatenation operator
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=temppath & "\Indications.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

    With wb
        With .Worksheets(1)   '<~~set this properly!
            rw = Application.Match(findThis, .Columns("D"), 0)
            If Not IsError(rw) Then
                Debug.Print .Cells(rw, "Q").Value
                Debug.Print .Cells(rw, "R").Value
                Debug.Print .Cells(rw, "S").Value
                Debug.Print .Cells(rw, "T").Value
                strQ = .Cells(rw, "Q").Value
                strR = .Cells(rw, "R").Value
                strS = .Cells(rw, "S").Value
                strT = .Cells(rw, "T").Value
                Debug.Print strQ
                Debug.Print strR
                Debug.Print strS
                Debug.Print strT
            Else
                Debug.Print findThis & " not found."
            End If
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Once the row number of returned through MATCH, the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) can easily return the values from any column on the same row.

Comment: Please note that the search term must match the entire cell value but it is not case sensitive.

Comment: Cant I assign that value to a variable like                                                  Dim value1 As String,                Set value1  = Debug.Print .Cells(rw, "Q").Value

Comment: Use `dim str as string` then `str = .Cells(rw, "Q").Value`. You only need to `Set` objects; you don't need it to assign a string value. See my edit above.

Comment: True Match is much faster for single column `xlWhole` searches :)